# javascript in html adding html type WITHOUT removing the rest of the type

Tags: javascript, html, output

so i have the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> THISISATITLE </TITLE>

<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">

function afunc(){
 var a=document.getElementById("input1").value; var a=parseInt(a); window.a=a;
 if(isNaN(a)){alert('Please enter a number');}
 else if(a<0){alert('Please enter a number greater than 0');}
 else{
  var b=document.getElementById("input2").value; var b=parseInt(b); window.b=b; alert('lol');
 }
}

</SCRIPT>

<input id="button1" type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="afunc();">

<p> </p>

<input id="input1" type="number" value="1"
<p> First Unit Attack </p>

<input id="input2" type="number" value="1"
<p> First Unit Defense </p>

<input id="input3" type="number" value="1"
<p> First Unit Speed </p>

<input id="input4" type="number" value="1"
<p> Second Unit Attack </p>

<input id="input5" type="number" value="1"
<p> Second Unit Defense </p>

<input id="input6" type="number" value="1"
<p> Second Unit Speed </p>

<p> words here </p>

<p id="input1"></p>

</HEAD>

<BODY>
THISISABODY
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

and i would like to have it so that when clicking the button and running afunc that variable a shows up at the end of the html but doesn't clear the rest of the text. i looked here:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_confirm

and tried to do something similar but it doesn't show up at all. if i do document.write or document.writeln it clears the rest of the page...

Comment: Your script runs before DOM is rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is your input tags in the head tag?

you have to add the variable in the body as shown in the below code.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <TITLE>THISISATITLE</TITLE>

  <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
    function afunc() {
      var a = document.getElementById("input1").value;
      var a = parseInt(a);
      window.a = a;
      if (isNaN(a)) {
        alert('Please enter a number');
      } else if (a < 0) {
        alert('Please enter a number greater than 0');
      } else {
        var b = document.getElementById("input2").value;
        var b = parseInt(b);
        window.b = b;
                       /* you have to add this line to show value of a */
                       document.body.innerHTML +=a;
        alert('lol');
      }
    }
  </SCRIPT>

  <input id="button1" type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="afunc();">

  <p></p>

  <input id="input1" type="number" value="1" <p>First Unit Attack</p>

  <input id="input2" type="number" value="1" <p>First Unit Defense</p>

  <input id="input3" type="number" value="1" <p>First Unit Speed</p>

  <input id="input4" type="number" value="1" <p>Second Unit Attack</p>

  <input id="input5" type="number" value="1" <p>Second Unit Defense</p>

  <input id="input6" type="number" value="1" <p>Second Unit Speed</p>

  <p>words here</p>

  <p id="input1"></p>

</HEAD>

<BODY>
  THISISABODY
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

So first off, all that HTML (your form) in your script tag is in the wrong spot, it all should be inside the BODY tag.

Once you have that in place, make a div or some other container for your output (we'll call it 'output') and then you can do something like this:

```
var output = document.getElementById('output');
output.innerHTML = b; // assuming 'b' is the variable that you want to write there
```

You could also do some DOM manipulation using things like `appendChild` and such, but `innerHTML` is simple enough for what you're describing.